# Camunda Incident Handler Spring boot

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

Is there any implementation example of Camunda 7 Incident Handler using Spring boot. With bpmn flow integrated.

I have already followed this https://forum.camunda.io/t/custom-incident-handler/3747

Code doesn't move to external task failure listener even if the incident is created in camunda cockpit.